# How to Auto Login and Redirect After Registration in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.0 and i have made custom registeration page in opencart.After successful registration i am redirecting to myaccount page but it will redirect to login page.
Can anybody help me in this to sort out the problem?

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: @siddhesh after completing registration i am not able to redirect to myaccount page it will redirect to me on login page.

Comment: Show your code what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

Here's my controller code :-

```
public function register() {
        $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');

        $json = array();


        //if (!$json) {
            $this->load->model('account/customer');

            if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) > 32)) {
                $json['error']['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
            }

            /*if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) > 32)) {
                $json['error']['lastname'] = $this->language->get('error_lastname');
            }*/

            if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || !preg_match('/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/', $this->request->post['email'])) {
                $json['error']['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
            }

            if ($this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomersByEmail($this->request->post['email'])) {
                $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
            }

            if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 32)) {
                $json['error']['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
            }

            /*if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) < 3) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) > 128)) {
                $json['error']['address_1'] = $this->language->get('error_address_1');
            }

            if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['city'])) < 2) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['city'])) > 128)) {
                $json['error']['city'] = $this->language->get('error_city');
            }

            $this->load->model('localisation/country');

            $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->post['country_id']);

            if ($country_info && $country_info['postcode_required'] && (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['postcode'])) < 2 || utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['postcode'])) > 10)) {
                $json['error']['postcode'] = $this->language->get('error_postcode');
            }

            if ($this->request->post['country_id'] == '') {
                $json['error']['country'] = $this->language->get('error_country');
            }

            if (!isset($this->request->post['zone_id']) || $this->request->post['zone_id'] == '') {
                $json['error']['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone');
            }*/

            if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) < 4) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) > 20)) {
                $json['error']['password'] = $this->language->get('error_password');
            }

            if ($this->request->post['confirm'] != $this->request->post['password']) {
                $json['error']['confirm'] = $this->language->get('error_confirm');
            }

            /*if ($this->config->get('config_account_id')) {
                $this->load->model('catalog/information');

                $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($this->config->get('config_account_id'));

                if ($information_info && !isset($this->request->post['agree'])) {
                    $json['error']['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_agree'), $information_info['title']);
                }
            } */

            // Customer Group
            if (isset($this->request->post['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($this->request->post['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
                $customer_group_id = $this->request->post['customer_group_id'];
            } else {
                $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
            }

            // Custom field validation
            $this->load->model('account/custom_field');

            $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($customer_group_id);

            foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
                if ($custom_field['required'] && empty($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['location']][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {
                    $json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                }
            }
        //}

        //if (!$json) {
            $customer_id = $this->model_account_customer->addCustomer($this->request->post);

            // Clear any previous login attempts for unregistered accounts.
            $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);

            $this->session->data['account'] = 'register';

            $this->load->model('account/customer_group');

            $customer_group_info = $this->model_account_customer_group->getCustomerGroup($customer_group_id);

            /*if ($customer_group_info && !$customer_group_info['approval']) {
                $this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password']);

                // Default Payment Address
                $this->load->model('account/address');

                $this->session->data['payment_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());

                if (!empty($this->request->post['shipping_address'])) {
                    $this->session->data['shipping_address'] = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->customer->getAddressId());
                }
            } else {*/
                $json['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/account');
            //}

            unset($this->session->data['guest']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);

            // Add to activity log
            $this->load->model('account/activity');

            $activity_data = array(
                'customer_id' => $customer_id,
                'name'        => $this->request->post['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->request->post['lastname']
            );

            $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('register', $activity_data);
        //}

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
```